# @PathVariable vs @RequestBody (which one and when ?)

Tags: java, spring

I am curious about a best practise on when one should pass to a controller in Java Spring boot a `@PathVariable` value (in its URL) vs to pass that value to the body of the request via `@RequestBody`.
I know that `ids` (as identifiers in the Database) are best passed as `@PathVariables` but what about `String`(s) and other types (especially if they are identifiers on the frontend side)? the purpose could be to find by name or by id or other fields.

Thank you,

Comment: "Find by ..." are search operations, and should not use path variables. Use either GET with *query* parameters, or POST with request body, in part depending on potential size of the search parameters.

Comment: i think you are missing the point of the question here, i was talking about the possibilty of passing string type values as parameters in the API controller's URI is it possible to find by name for example ?

Comment: Is name a *unique* identifier of the resource? Is "other fields" uniquely identifying a single resource? A particular resource should only have one URL path to directly 'GET' it, since REST considers the URL path to be the unique identify of the resource, so you shouldn't have both `.../item/byid/42` and `.../item/byname/foo` for a resource. You should use `GET .../item/42` and `GET .../item?name=foo` or `POST .../item/search` with `foo` in the payload. --- But to answer, yes, you can use `GET .../item/foo`, but you should only do that if "foo" cannot contain special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would the API look?

`/users/{searchterm}`

So you can call it with

`/users/42`

as well as

`/users/anton`

I think I would prefer a query parameter instead, so it becomes something like

`/users/42` if I know the specific ID, else

`/users?search=eq('name','anton')`

Comment: There are also some fine suggestions for filtering on this page https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/